# Joomla 4 Component json output

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-4, joomla-4.1

I'm building a simple Joomla 4 component, and I need to use a json view for some ajax requests.  Just starting the testing process, and ran into an odd seemingly unrelated error message. I don't get this in HTML views, and the session storage is set to database.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: \Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Development\xampp\tmp) in <b>C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Development\xampp\htdocs\joomla\libraries\vendor\joomla\session\src\Storage\NativeStorage.php</b> on line <b>114</b><br />
```

**My URL:**
http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_testcomponent&view=json&format=json

**site\src\View\Json\JsonView.php**

```
<?php

namespace Joomla\Component\Testcomponent\Site\View\Json;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\JsonView as BaseJsonView;

class JsonView extends BaseJsonView
{
    public $json;
    
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $array = [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2',
            'key3' => 'value3',
            'key4' => 'value4'
        ];
        $this->json = json_encode($array);
        
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

**site\tmpl\json\json.php**

```
<?= $this->json; ?>
```

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, however yesterday I was working with a Fetch in JS passing data to a Joomla 4 component and started receiving the same message. I found reloading the page was the only cure. In my case I am passing JSON but not using the &Format=JSON. I kind of agree with your suggestion that it is probably unrelated or at least not directly.

Comment: Thanks @Irata, I tried loading the URL in an incognito browser, and the page is simply blank instead of the error display.  Starting to wonder if this is a bug of some sort, but I'm not sure how to track it down.

Comment: If you have debug enabled, it's a bug and you should report it to developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this to the Joomla Issue Tracker.
https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/39341